# Qt selectionChanged stops working after data is reloaded to qtreeview

Tags: python, qt

There is a Qtreeview filled with data from dictionary, when selection changed on this treeview then some data is shown on the QLabel.

When dictionary is updated (by double click on the other Qtreeview) I call function that initially loads data to Qtreeview. New data is shown but selectionChanged doesn't work anymore.

What I do wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#from PySide.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

data_for_tree = {"tomato":{"color":"red","ammount":"10", "note":"a note for tomato","price":"0.8"},"banana":{"color":"yellow","ammount":"1", "note":"b note for banana", "price":".6"}, "some fruit":{"color":"unknown","ammount":"100", "note":"some text","price":"2.1"}}
data_for_receiver = {"1":{"name":"milk","price":"3.2","note":"I love milk"}, "2":{"name":"coca-cola","price":".8","note":"coke forever"}}

class ProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)
        try:
            return float(leftData) < float(rightData)
        except ValueError:
            return leftData < rightData

class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.infoLable = QLabel()
        self.MyTreeView = QTreeView()
        self.MyTreeViewModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.MyTreeView.setModel(self.MyTreeViewModel)
        self.most_used_cat_header = ['Name', "ammount", "color"]
        self.MyTreeViewModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.most_used_cat_header)
        self.MyTreeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.MyTreeView_Fill()
        self.receiver_tree = QTreeView()
        self.receiver_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.receiver_tree.setModel(self.receiver_model)
        self.receiver_tree_header = ['#','Name', "price"]
        self.receiver_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.receiver_tree_header)
        self.MyTreeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.addToReceiver)
        self.receiver_tree.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.showInfo)
        self.receiver_fill()

        MainWindow = QVBoxLayout(self)    
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.infoLable)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.MyTreeView)
        MainWindow.addWidget(self.receiver_tree)
        self.setLayout(MainWindow)
    def showInfo(self):
        indexes = self.receiver_tree.selectedIndexes()
        index_list =[i.data() for i in     self.receiver_tree.selectedIndexes()]
        name = index_list[1]
        price = index_list[2]
        txt = str(name) + " " + str(price)
        self.infoLable.setText(txt)
    def addToReceiver(self):
        indexes = self.MyTreeView.selectedIndexes()
        index_list =[i.data() for i in     self.MyTreeView.selectedIndexes()]
        last_id = max(int(i) for i in data_for_receiver)
        for k in data_for_tree:
            v = data_for_tree[k]
            if [k,v["ammount"],v["color"]] == index_list:
                i =QStandardItem(str(last_id+1))
                name = QStandardItem(k)
                price = QStandardItem(format(float(v["price"]), ".2f"))
                tooltip = v["note"]
                name.setToolTip(tooltip)
                item = ( i, name, price)
                #self.receiver_model.appendRow(item)
                upd  = {"name":k,"price":v["price"],"note":v["note"]}
                data_for_receiver[str(last_id+1)] = upd
                self.receiver_model = QStandardItemModel()
                self.receiver_tree.setModel(self.receiver_model)
                self.receiver_fill()

    def MyTreeView_Fill(self):
        for k in data_for_tree:
            name = QStandardItem(k)
            ammount = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["ammount"])
            note = QStandardItem(data_for_tree[k]["color"])
            name.setEditable(False)
            tooltip = "price "+format(float(data_for_tree[k]["price"]), ".2f")+"<br>"
            tooltip += data_for_tree[k]["note"]
            item = (name, ammount, note)
            name.setToolTip(tooltip)
            self.MyTreeViewModel.appendRow(item)
        self.MyTreeView.sortByColumn(1, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        proxyModel = ProxyModel(self)
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.MyTreeViewModel)
        self.MyTreeView.setModel(proxyModel)
        c = 0
        while c < len(self.most_used_cat_header):
            self.MyTreeView.resizeColumnToContents(c)
            c=c+1

    def receiver_fill(self):
        for k in data_for_receiver:
            v = data_for_receiver[k]
            i = QStandardItem(k)
            name = QStandardItem(v["name"])
            price = QStandardItem(format(float(v["price"]), ".2f"))
            tooltip = v["note"]
            name.setToolTip(tooltip)
            item = (i,name, price)
            self.receiver_model.appendRow(item)
        c = 0
        while c < len(self.receiver_tree_header):
            self.receiver_tree.resizeColumnToContents(c)
            c=c+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    main.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() -     main.rect().center())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that you create and set new `QStandardItemModel` each time in `addToReceiver`. `QAbstractItemView::setModel` method documentation says that it causes view to re-create selection model, and the signal connection gets lost. You should use `self.receiver_model.clear()` instead and remove `setModel` call.